# How to iterate over this series 5 6 7 6 5 6 7 6 5 6 7 6 5... in C?

Tags: c, loops, sequence, series

How lo obtain that sequence of digits in C?
I tried sth but it didn't answer the question

Comment: Loop forever on `printf("%d %d %d %d ",5,6,7,6);`  - Now, what have *you* tried ?

Comment: you can simply do with python as:



`for i in range(num):
        print (6+round(math.sin(math.radians(90*i))))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int seq(void){
    static int v = 5, d = 1;
    int ret = v;
    v += d;
    if(v == 5 || v == 7) d = -d;
    return ret;
}

int main(void) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        printf("%d ", seq());
    return 0;
}
```